# Windows 8.1 boot into copied partition

Tags: boot, partitioning, windows-8.1

I have a laptop with a mSATA HDD and a normal (spinning) HDD. On the mSATA is an Ubuntu installation, while on the HDD, there is a Windows 8.1.

The laptop boots from the mSATA where I have a boot entry chainloading Windows 8.1. Works like a charm.

I now put a 3rd HDD (SSD) into my laptop, which is to replace the HDD (functionally). I went ahead and used `gparted`, to copy the partitions from the HDD onto the SSD. I can mount and use these copied partitions just fine.

However, I cannot boot into the SSD, i.e. the copied partitions. It doesn't matter which HDD I select from the BIOS boot menu, or which disk I chainload from GRUB, I always end up booting the old Windows. Which means not the copied partitions, but the original ones. I suppoese some portion of the Windows 8.1 boot loader selects which disk to boot from and of course I copied that along. But how do I change it? How do I tell windows 8.1 which disk and partition to boot from. Older Windows versions had a `boot.ini`. Windows 8.1 doesn't seem to have that mechanism anymore ...

Comment: +1 I have exactly the same problem. It seems that the boot loader in the cloned partition selects the original hard drive for booting. Possibly [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff541231%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) might help, but I have not yet tried it

Comment: @hochl I learned a few things about Windows in the mean time. You have to edit the "BCD" to make the booting happen. For that you need a rescue CD. Quite painful procedure because they chose to make it so. To end up with a working Windows you probably also have to change UUID to drive letter mappings in the registry. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This might be a Windows Boot Manager issue.

Try this:

1. Go into msconfig via Run (Windows Key  + R, type 'msconfig', enter)
2. Click the boot tab
3. Verify that all your settings are correct.

Comment: And what do correct settings look like? The entries are there. I have a `C:\Windows` and a `E:\Windows` entry. However when i select the e: entry for booting the laptop will reboot after a few seconds. If I select that disk for booting from the bios menu i get a missing winload.exe. (This is some progress comparted to when I worte that question. However I cant just bcdrebuild as the internet suggests for this new problem.)

Comment: @DavidPostill I would appreciate it if you would stop changing every single one of my answers.  ***It's ridiculous***.

Comment: @user1129682 Missing winload.exe suggests that Windows Boot Manager has been either removed or disabled.

Comment: @TomWebPerson http://superuser.com/help/behavior: **Do not use signature, taglines, or greetings.** Every post you make is already “signed” with your standard user card, which links directly back to your user page. If you use an additional signature or tagline, it will be removed to reduce noise in the questions and answers.

Comment: @DavidPostill Thank you for explaining this to me.